# Telegram bot inline keyboard markup callback usage for channel messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, keyboard, telegram, telegram-bot

My Telegram bot needs to send messages to channel and provide inline keyboard for every message, it looks like this: [inline message keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH0Vm.png)

I need to react on this keyboard button click event, but I can't find docs or examples showing how to do it. [Here in docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup) I can only see that such buttons can open URL or switch chat, but it's not the functionality I need.

Currently my code for message sending looks like this (I use NodeJS Telegraf framework):

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
const { Markup, Telegram } = Telegraf;

const telegram = new Telegram(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);

const inlineMessageRatingKeyboard = [[
    { text: '', callback_data: 'like' },
    { text: '', callback_data: 'dislike' }
]];

telegram.sendMessage(
    process.env.TELEGRAM_CHANNEL,
    'test',
    { reply_markup: JSON.stringify({ inline_keyboard: inlineMessageRatingKeyboard }) }
    )
);
```

So, I need to know, how to make bot react on inline message keyboard interaction in channel messages.

Comment: Its been a really long time since I have developed Telegram bots but when I was using it on Python I have to use this command "CallbackQueryHandler("your method to reply to the inline message )". So have a look at the documentation of Telegraf and search for something like CallbackQueryHandler

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use event `action()` or in TelegrafContext with `callbackQuery()` and `answerCallbackQuery()`
context methods on [GitHubGist](https://gist.github.com/dzNET/5d727e7723a6c50f1ba7e98197938f24)

it's work:

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf')
const { Router, Markup } = Telegraf

const telegram = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)

const inlineMessageRatingKeyboard = Markup.inlineKeyboard([
    Markup.callbackButton('', 'like'),
    Markup.callbackButton('', 'dislike')
]).extra()

telegram.on('message', (ctx) => ctx.telegram.sendMessage(
    ctx.from.id,
    'Like?',
    inlineMessageRatingKeyboard)
)

telegram.action('like', (ctx) => ctx.editMessageText(' Awesome! '))
telegram.action('dislike', (ctx) => ctx.editMessageText('okey'))

telegram.startPolling()
```

full example [here](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/develop/examples/custom-router-bot.js)

Comment: Is there a way to pass a parameter to the callback function?